# Is there anyway to access the localhost of Blazor Server from the client side?

Tags: iframe, blazor, localhost, blazor-server-side

I have multiple web applications that are available on `localhost` on my server in various ports; for example:

```
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:3040
http://localhost:5510
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to render those web applications via `iframe`s within a Blazor Server app; something like this:

```
@page "/web-apps"

<PageTitle>Web Apps</PageTitle>

<iframe src="http://localhost:8080"></iframe>
```

While the Blazor Server app is being accessed from within the server, obviously, everything works and `iframe` shows whatever is available in endpoints mentioned above;

[image]

But if I try to access the server using the public IP of the server (over the internet), `iframe` will be blank.

I know the reason for this is that when accessing the Blazor Server app over the internet, `localhost` no longer points to the server that is running the Blazor Server app but the user's client side.

Is there anyway to render the content of web applications without exposing their endpoints over public IP? (i.e. keeping them accessible only on the `localhost` of the server)

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the client (browser) is making a request then it must - by definition - use a public endpoint. How do you expect to be able to access private resources from a public address?